# when popup by jquery ajax is showing is it possible reloading current popup by refresh(f5)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, popup, refresh

is it possible?

jquery ajax popup => refresh (f5)
=> jquery ajax popup reloading

Can I keep the pop-up so that I can reload the screen right now if I refresh?

view code

```
# todo 상세 보기
class todoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Todo
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return ['todo/_todo_detail.html']
        return ['todo/_todo_detail.html']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(todoDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = CommentForTodo.objects.filter(todo=self.object.pk)
        context['detail_id'] = self.object.pk
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        return context
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    $("#todo_list a[class='title_for_list']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        window.history.pushState("", "", '/todo/'+id)
        $.get(id)
            .done((html) => {
                console.log(html);
                $('#myModal_button').hide();
                $("#myModal").html(html)
                $( "#myModal_button" ).trigger( "click" );
            })
            .fail(() => {
                console.log("fail");
            })
            .always(() => {
                console.log('always');
            })
    });
})
```

Comment: `$("#modelid").trigger('click');` this will solve your issue.